# How can I change the link behind a button via my NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

This is the code I am using to dynamically change text in my UITextView based on which item is selected in my NSArray.

```
NSMutableString *flavorsText = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString* preworkout in self.preWorkout.flavors) {
    [flavorsText appendFormat:@"%@\n", preworkout];
}

self.flavorsTextView.text = flavorsText;
```

I am curious as to how I can change the link behind a single button based on the link that is typed into the NSArray. I want it to have the same functionality as this code above basically.

Comment: What's the default link? What does the button do?

Comment: It would be a single button that says Buy Now! However the button would be in a view controller that has it's information changed based on the objects in the NSArray. The button links to a store website.

Comment: Post the method that is called when you tap the button.

Comment: Thats sort of what i'm asking, everything I need to do to make it work. For example this is the code i'm using for the above example.    //@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *flavorsTextView; and //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *flavors; // flavors available.

Comment: what do you mean by link?

Comment: As in a web link such as http://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: If someone can help me successfully answer this question I will either give them reddit gold or $5 amazon code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the URL somewhere. Add a property to your class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *storeURL;
```

The button code should look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buyNow:(id)sender
{
    [someWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.storeURL]];
}
```

When the user changes the selection, update the `storeURL` property with the new URL.

Comment: Alright this makes sense however just for clarification, what is someWebView? I'm not implementing any web views in my view controller.

Comment: If you aren't implementing a UIWebView in your interface, how do you plan on loading the links? I would advise against kicking the user out to Safari, but here's how you would do that: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:self.storeURL];`

Comment: That was the plan actually, to push them to safari to view the webpage. Why do you recommend against this?

Comment: Also would I make storeUrl = to an NSString?

Comment: It's generally bad practice to kick the user out of the app for any reason. And no, you really should use NSURL for URLs. Both of the code snippets I used require NSURL, not NSString.

Comment: Would you make storeUrl = to an NSString?

Comment: So what property am i loading into my NSArray to edit the URL for each object. In my example code above I would do. object1.flavors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apple Ambush", nil];

Comment: Would you be able to help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have an array, `someArrayOfLinks`, that contains `NSString` url strings, correct?

So, as you know arrays are based on indexes, so `someArrayOfLinks[9]` gives you the 10th item in the array (starts at 0). All `UIView` objects and their subclasses feature a tag property that holds an integer. So, what I'd do is something like this:

**Wherever you are setting the flavors:**

```
self.buyNowButton.tag = someInteger;
```

**Then, when they tap the button**

```
- (IBAction)didSelectBuyNowButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *urlPath = someArrayOfLinks[sender.tag];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:url];
}
```

Comment: My NSArray is not showing up, shouldn't I be typing it where someArrayOfLinks is? Also what's the difference between buyNowButton.tag and didSelectBuyNowButton. Also what is someInteger and openUrl supposed to be?

Comment: Buy yes I have an NSArray with multiple objects such a name,company name, flavors, sizes and info and I basically want to have a object = an nsstring which houses the link. Just how flavors equals an NSArray above.

Comment: If you download the source code for this application https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/RecipeAppSearchBar.zip you can see almost exactly how I have my NSArray set up and how the objects are connected to it in the RecipeDetailViewController.h and .m and the Recipe.h files.